# Functional testing problem using Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

We have got a problem while testing Android apps. Our architecture is as follows: there are two apk files installed on device, first apk file gives link to open specific app and second apk actually runs that app. Now there are two processes which actually runs app. We are able to invoke first process (apk) using Robotium, then Robotium clicks on specific link to open specific app but we are unable to click anywhere when app is launched. The app is run by second process (apk). We are at conclusion that Robotium will not work to get activities from second process because it sticks to one process and that is called instrumentation.

Now what do you recommend?

Is there any other tool or approach to overcome this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From my research I havent found an easy way around this.  I implemented a workaround that seems to give our products the coverage we need though.

1) Have a Robotium suite test the first apk.
2) When you launch the second apk, have a separate Robotium suite that can test that.

Now between these two things there is something you have to assume.  You have to assume the fact that the second apk was launched correctly for those Robotium tests to pass.

For example: 
Robotium tests the first apk launcher activity.  From this apk you can still test that the second apk launches. Then stop that Robotium test suite there.
Now your second Robotium test suite should invoke launcher activity for the second apk.
You can script this out in a bash file, or some other script.